# Creating a list of tuples(?) from a list and list of lists of even length

Tags: python, list, tuples

Given that

```
a = ['1', '2']
b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

How could I get these lists into a format like `[('1', 'a', 'b'), ('2', 'c', 'd')]`? I tried to zip them together, but I don't want `b` as a list. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zip is still your friend:

```
[tuple([x] + y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[tuple([x] + y) for x, y in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of making it complex, a simpler approach would be to flatten the nested tuple/list

```
>>> a = ['1', '2']
>>> b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> zip(a, *b)
[('1', 'a', 'c'), ('2', 'b', 'd')]
```

Comment: But this does not yield the result OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use list comprehension, you could do:

```
zip(a, *(zip(*b)))
```

For example:

```
a = ['1', '2']
b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

new_list = zip(a, *(zip(*b)))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[('1', 'a', 'b'), ('2', 'c', 'd')]
```